# search associative array by value

Tags: php

I'm fetching some JSON from flickrs API. My problem is that the exif data is in different order depending on the camera. So I can't hard-code an array number to get, for instance, the camera model below. Does PHP have any built in methods to search through associative array values and return the matching arrays? In my example below I would like to search for the `[label] => Model` and get `[_content] => NIKON D5100`.

Please let me know if you want me to elaborate.

```
print_r($exif['photo']['exif']);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tagspace] => IFD0
            [tagspaceid] => 0
            [tag] => Make
            [label] => Make
            [raw] => Array
                (
                    [_content] => NIKON CORPORATION
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tagspace] => IFD0
            [tagspaceid] => 0
            [tag] => Model
            [label] => Model
            [raw] => Array
                (
                    [_content] => NIKON D5100
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tagspace] => IFD0
            [tagspaceid] => 0
            [tag] => XResolution
            [label] => X-Resolution
            [raw] => Array
                (
                    [_content] => 240
                )

            [clean] => Array
                (
                    [_content] => 240 dpi
                )

        )
```

Comment: @Jogan could you please help me out with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721195/php-how-do-i-apply-multiple-filtering-conditions-passed-as-an-array-of-arrays ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such function. There is [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), but it doesn't quite do what you want.

I think the easiest way would be to write a loop yourself.

```
function search_exif($exif, $field)
{
    foreach ($exif as $data)
    {
        if ($data['label'] == $field)
            return $data['raw']['_content'];
    }
}

$camera = search_exif($exif['photo']['exif'], 'model');
```

Comment: Thanks for the generic solution :-)

Comment: However, i think that `in` should be `as`. And `then` should be removed?

Comment: @Johan. Indeed, when using multiple programming languages, you sometimes mix them up. :)

Answer (score 90):

```
$key = array_search('model', array_column($data, 'label'));
```

In more recent versions of PHP, specifically PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, the function above will work.

Comment: I think this answer is the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 17):

`$key = array_search('Model', array_map(function($data) {return $data['label'];}, $exif))`

The array_map() function sends each value of an array to a user-made function, and returns an array with new values, given by the user-made function. In this case we are returning the label.

The array_search() function search an array for a value and returns the key. (in this case we are searching the returned array from array_map for the label value 'Model')

Comment: I like this method a lot better than the rest listed here! Its true PHP, and personally a lot faster than the traditional foreach method. Someone benchmark this!

Comment: Is there any proof about performance of `array_search` + `array_map` vs loop?

Comment: Can you add some explanation to you code such that others can learn from it?

Comment: I have added some explanation @NicoHasse

Comment: Although the answer by @AriefHidayatulloh might be better?  
The array_column() function returns the values from a single column in the input array.

Answer (score 5):

This would be fairly trivial to implement:

```
$model = '';

foreach ($exif['photo']['exif'] as $data) {
    if ($data['label'] == 'Model') {
        $model = $data['raw']['_content'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($exif['photo']['exif'] as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == "label" AND $v == "Model")
            $needle[] = $row["raw"];
    }
}
print_r($needle);
```

Comment: its better to use not a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following function, searches in an associative array both for string values and values inside other arrays. For example , given the following array

```
 $array= [  "one" => ["a","b"],
            "two" => "c" ];
```

the following function can find both a,b and c as well

```
 function search_assoc($value, $array){
         $result = false;
         foreach ( $array as $el){
             if (!is_array($el)){
                 $result = $result||($el==$value);
             }
             else if (in_array($value,$el))
                 $result= $result||true;
             else $result= $result||false;
         }
         return $result;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [
["name"=>"mostafa","email"=>"mostafa@gmail.com"],
["name"=>"ali","email"=>"ali@gmail.com"],
["name"=>"nader","email"=>"nader@gmail.com"]];

chekFromItem($data,"ali");

function chekFromItem($items,$keyToSearch)
{
$check = false;
foreach($items as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $key)
    {
        if($key == $keyToSearch)
        {
            $check = true;
        }
    }

    if($check == true)
    {break;}
}
return $check;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , PHP does not have in built-in search function for multidimensional array. It has only for indexed and associative array. Therefore you have to write your own search function!!