# how to search in array to find all sub arrays that contain a certain value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have a array placed in the variable `$class` that is constituted of sub arrays containing 2 student id's each,
i am trying to find all the sub arrays that contain a certain `id` for example `11` 
i want to keep all arrays containing this id in a variable.

**array example**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [s1] => 6
            [s2] => 37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [s1] => 8
            [s2] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [s1] => 11
            [s2] => 48
        )

)
```

**code**

```
foreach ($class as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($id, $class)){
        unset($class[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `if(!in_array($id, $class)){` to `if(!in_array($id, $value)){` - Also, but this might come down to personal preference: I'm not a huge fan of altering an array while looping over it. While it may seem generally safe in PHP I've just grown used to not doing that. In this particular case I'd just put all **matching** values into a new array and leave the original un-altered.

Comment: @ccKep still getting an empty Array()

Comment: [Works fine for me?](https://3v4l.org/q29e7) Are you doing that multiple times with different IDs? Since you're altering the original `$class` array, a second search might give unexpected results (eg. searching for `6` after searching for `11` returns an empty array since the first search reduced the array to only pairs containing an `11`, and neither of those pairs contains a `6` anymore)

Comment: Woops... I was writing up the answer, and you were already describing the same thing in comments! My bad.

Comment: your array structure is different than mine

Comment: @mirvatJ I used the exact structure you posted in the question, down to the associative indexes on the inner arrays and their values.

Comment: i am not doing that multiple times

Comment: @ccKep, Your link has `!in_array($id, $value)` (correct), but the question has `!in_array($id, $class)` (wrong). This could explain the different results.

Comment: @ccKep even if i change it to the way you did it, which makes sense, it still returning empty array

Comment: @jh1711 That's exactly what I wrote the OP to change in the first comment up there. The link is merely a response to "still getting an empty array" (I assumed "still" referred to "after changing that part")

Comment: @mirvatJ Then you're not giving all the required information in this question. As shown by the link, this code works for the structure you provided.

Comment: @ccKep, sorry I didn't read the earlier comments. My bad.

Comment: @ccKep my bad had `$id` not defined, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. If you loop and reference the correct variable with the in_array(), it would work as you hopefully need. Then assign the matching array into a new array var to use later (so you are not altering your original array!):

```
$id = 11;
$matched = array();
foreach ($class as $i => $students) {
    if ( in_array($id, $students) ) {
        $matched[] = $class[$i];
    }
}

print_r($matched);
```

Would result in:

```
Array (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [s1] => 8
             [s2] => 11
         )
     [1] => Array
         (
             [s1] => 11
             [s2] => 48
         )
     )
```

Comment: `$matched[] = $students;` would also work in the above example.

Answer (score -1):

Associative array
http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php

```
$class = array(array("s1"=>6, "s2"=>37),array("s1"=>8,"s2"=>11),array("s1"=>11, "s2"=>48));
$id = 11;
foreach ($class as $key => $value) {
    if(!array_search($id, $value)){
        unset($class[$key]);
    }
}
```

Sorry, you can follow this answers
[using array_search for multi dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694843/using-array-search-for-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: You're not using `array_search` safely, read the big red warning for the return value.

Comment: You're right 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376992/search-associative-array-by-value