# searching for a value in associative array, php

Tags: php, mysql

I have put all the users table in an associative array called $row, and i need to search for the row where the user got a specific id, how to do that, this is the code if it helps:

```sql
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
```

So now i need to get from $row (using php and not sql) the information where id = 1;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [search associative array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376992/search-associative-array-by-value)

Comment: `$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1";`

Comment: $query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$row[user_id]; are you expecting like this ? or can you please provide full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$row['id'];
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
```

I hope your requirement will be helpful by this above code. Please comment.

Comment: `$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
    
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);                                                            
  `

Comment: my point is that i did 2 queries that are the same as the first one you wrote, i need to compare the user id (in users table) to user id(in post table), after those queries i had this code.
`do{
      do{
            if($row1['id'] == $row2['user_id']){
?>
    <h3><?php echo $row1['username']; ?></h3>
<?php
     }
 }while($row1['id'] != $row2['user_id']);
?>
   <h4>
        <?php echo $row2['post_title']; ?>
   </h4>
   <p> 
        <?php echo $row2['post_content']; ?>
   </p>
<?php
    } while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2) and $row2['user_id'] != $_SESSION['userid'])`

Comment: and sorry for the way i post it seems messy but still new to this site and i don't yet know how to use it, thank you for the help.